# Ruby on rails application with single http endpoint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Can someone explain what "app with single end point" means in term of rails? How do I set up this endpoint?

Comment: Please give the context of the phrase "app with single end point".

Comment: I have to write application with single http end point. That endpoint should receive any data it's sent, and pass it down a rabbitmq message queue

Answer (score 0):

It means that there is only one API method. For example:

```
POST /messages
```

All other requests to the Rails app will return status 404 Not Found.

You can do it if you put this in `config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :messages, only: [:create]
end
```

Then put the following in `app/controllers/messages_controller.rb`:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def create

  end
end
```

This `create` method will receive the input.

You can use the [Bunny](https://rubygems.org/gems/bunny) gem to send it to a RabbitMQ exchange.

Comment: Okey thanks, so i cant create messages by html form?

Comment: This requirement wasn't in your question. You can. But then you also need a view and other actions. So it is better to just run `rails generate scaffold message body:text`. It will generate a lot of files. Keep and edit the ones you need.

Comment: Yes i know but will it be still application with single http end point?

Comment: With the scaffold, no :)

Comment: So to keep this app with single end point,there is only possibility to create messages by command line?

Comment: So how should create method look?

Comment: It's a different question. Off-topic for this question.